# Appending to an array in another file

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to create data in one file, and then append it to a table in another file permeanantly so that every time I append, the other file updates even if I save and quit the program.

I tried to import this other python file:

```
# database.py

table = [
["cars", "boats", "trains"], 
["peanut butter", "jelly", "bread"]
]
```

and append another array to it:

```
# main.py

from database import table

row = ["apples", "oranges", "pears"]

table.append(row)
```

to create in the database file:

```
# database.py

table = [
["cars", "boats", "trains"], 
["peanut butter", "jelly", "bread"],
["apples", "oranges", "pears"]
]
```

and I expected this to work, but instead the addition was only temporary, and did not save to the `database.py` file.

How could I do this?

Answer (score 1):

#### Store the data in a data file that is not executable Python

For example, in the first file, write out the value:

```
# write.py

import json

table = [
["cars", "boats", "trains"], 
["peanut butter", "jelly", "bread"]
]

with open("data_file.json", "w") as f:
    json.dump(table, f)
```

Then you can amend it like this:

```
# append.py

import json

with open("data_file.json","r") as f:
    table = json.load(f)

row = ["apples", "oranges", "pears"]
table.append(row)

with open("data_file.json", "w") as f:
    json.dump(table, f)
```

And you can print it out like this:

```
# read.py

import json

with open("data_file.json","r") as f:
    table = json.load(f)

print(table)
```

And at any time you can see the current version of data_file.json in any text editor.

Comment: I'm getting `json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)`

Comment: This means you have not run the code in the right order. Run the `write.py` file first. Use a text editor to confirm that the data_file.json is created and correct. Then run the `append.py` file, etc.